# QLabel inside QMenu

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm trying to add a [QLabel](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlabel.html) to a [QMenu](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qmenu.html) because I need to have word-wrapped text. But it just add a blank line to the menu.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class My(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.qapp = QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.status_icon = QSystemTrayIcon(QIcon.fromTheme('edit-delete'))
        contextMenu = QMenu()

        label = QLabel('foobar')
        action = QWidgetAction(self.qapp)
        action.setDefaultWidget(label)
        contextMenu.addAction(action)

        self.status_icon.setContextMenu(contextMenu)

    def run(self):
        self.status_icon.show()
        self.qapp.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    My().run()
```

[image: systrayicon]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The code above works for me on windows 8.0, Python 2.7.3 - 32-bit, PyQt v4.10.1, Qt v4.8.4. Might be some sort of issue with the window manager you are using in Linux?

Comment: Maybe Qt doesn't support embedding widgets in Unity's icon context menu or it's not possible at all.

Comment: You're both totally right. It doesn't work with Unity but with Kubuntu and Xubuntu. I'll investigate further if this is a bug or a 'feature'. I'd accept this as an answer.

Comment: It would be an answer if there was any proof link. I tried to find indicators API to find out if arbitrary widgets can be put in there, but didn't find anything useful.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with Lubuntu / LXDE, sad to see that this is not fixed yet

Answer (score 0):

Pass `QMenu` object when instantiating the `QWidgetAction`

```
action = QWidgetAction(contextMenu)
```

Your code works well in my signal/slot setup.

Comment: That doesn't help for Unity. Other DE's are fine with `QMenu` and `QApplication`.